# Cassandra data model for high ingestion rate and delete operation

Tags: cassandra

I am using the following Cassandra data model

```
ruleid - bigint
patternid - bigint
key - string
value - string 
time - timestamp
event_uuid -time based uuid
partition key - ruleid, patterid
clustering key - event_uuid order by descending
```

Our ingestion rate is around 100 records per second per pattern id and there might be 10 000+ pattern ids.

Our query is fairly straightforward we query the last 100 000 records based on the desc uuid filtered by the partition key.

Also for our use case we would need to perform around 5 deletes per second on this per pattern ids.

**However this leads to the so called tombstones and causes readtimeout on querying on the datastore again.**

How to overcome the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are storing records into the table, doing some transformation/processing on the records, then deleting them.

But since you're deleting rows within partitions (instead of the partitions themselves), you have to iterate over the deleted rows (tombstones) to get to the live records.

The real problem though is reading too many rows which won't perform well. Retrieving 100K rows is going to be slow so consider paging through the result set.

With limited information you've provided, this is not an easy problem to solve. Cheers!

Comment: We are currently paging using datastax driver. But our main concern is the tombstone creation. So it will be very helpful if there is any way to overcome this issue. We need the data only for 24 hours. We can also limit the delete to 1 million records per patternid  per day. So just want to ensure if this approach has feasibility.